# SIP stack with ICE, STUN, TURN, SIPS and ZRTP support

Tags: sip

As mentioned in the title, I'm looking for a complete SIP stack library that would integrate support for SIPS and ZRTP encryption mechanisms with ICE/STUN/TURN support.

I need a library written in C or C++ portable on Linux/OSX/Windows and I can't use GPL licensed library.

If anybody knows one :)

I already looked at pjsip but it uses GPL :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I decided to use baresip (and the associated libraries).